# SSO Implementation for the app designed using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, single-sign-on

I am having two web applications, Application "A" and Application "B".
Application "A" has Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity for authentication/Authorization.
Now, I want to implement SSO for access to Application B without Additional sign-in.

Please share your ideas.

**Note:** Application "A" is using email Ids as a username.

**Tools/Platforms:** VS2019,.Net core, SQL DB

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect
```

Install above packages to implement SSO and configure middleware, For more in detail please follow/read the [article](https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/web-app-sso/implementation-aspnetcore)